# Jquery navigation and sub navigation hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I am having some issues with jquery navigation. When I hover over a menu item a sub menu item appears and I can hover over those, my problem is that when I hover off the navigation item or any of the sub items, the submenu still appears. My question is how would I get my submenu items to not show when you over off the submenu items? if you hover off the menu item or the submenu item I am trying to get the submenu items to not show (I really hope this makes sense)

Here is my code:

```
    $(".galleryNavToggle").on("mouseenter", function (event) {
    $('#headerNavGallery, #headerNavInfo').hide();
    $("#headerNavGallery").show();
});

$(".galleryNavInfoToggle").on("mouseenter", function (event) {
    $('#headerNavGallery, #headerNavInfo').hide();
    $("#headerNavInfo").show();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="headerNav">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='galleryNavToggle'>Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='galleryNavInfoToggle'>Info</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--headerNav-->

<div class="headerNavGallery" id="headerNavGallery" style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li><a href="Categories.php?action=view">Categoies</a></li>
<li><a href="Products.php?action=view">Products</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--headerNavGallery-->

<div class="headerNavInfo" id="headerNavInfo" style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li><a href="willRuppel.php?action=view">William Ruppel</a></li>
<li><a href="CV.php?action=view">CV</a></li>
<li><a href="artistBio.php?action=view">Artist Bio</a></li>
<li><a href="Video.php?action=view">Video</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php?action=view">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--headerNavInfo-->
```

if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be awesome, has I had this issues for weeks now and cant find a solution you can see this at http://www.willruppelglass.com

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a decent tutorial for doing drop down style menus. You should check it out and refactor your html and css. You don't need to use javascript for drop down menus. 
http://www.threestyles.com/tutorials/css-drop-down-navigation-tutorial/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your navigation under one list and use `.hover()` to manipulate the `display` css attribute. Fiddle with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jdSjE/3/).

List hierarchy:

```
[nav container]
  [primary nav item]
    [secondary nav item]
    [secondary nav item]
  [primary nav item]
    [secondary nav item]
    [secondary nav item]
    [secondary nav item]
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#nav-container li.primary-nav-item').hover(
            function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'block'); },
            function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'none'); });
    });​
```

Comment: IT might make it easier if you had all your nav items under one list or div.